# Says X must be a value in logarithmic function?

Tags: python, math, logarithm

I have the following code:

```
import math
q = input("Is there a square root in the function? (y,n) ")
if q == "y":
  base = input("base? ")
  x_value = input("x? ")
  print (math.log(math.sqrt(base),x_value))
else:
  base_2 = input("base? ")
  x_value_2 = input("x? ")
  print (math.log(base_2, x_value_2))
```

When I run the code, it says that the second value in math.log() must be a number.  Shouldn't it work if I just use the variable I assigned to it?

Comment: Only if the variable references a number.

Comment: `input` returns a string even if you pass it a number.

Comment: You should look first this page: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns a string. You should convert the user inputs to floating numbers with the `float()` constructor:

```
import math
q = input("Is there a square root in the function? (y,n) ")
if q == "y":
  base = float(input("base? "))
  x_value = float(input("x? "))
  print (math.log(math.sqrt(base),x_value))
else:
  base_2 = float(input("base? "))
  x_value_2 = float(input("x? "))
  print (math.log(base_2, x_value_2))
```